# Laravel 5.5 | Tags only appear in the last post?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display tags of the posts , but when I tried to display, tags only appear in the last post.

Here my codes;

**BlogController;**

```
public function getSingle($slug){
    $posts = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('front.pages.single')->with('post', $posts);
}
```

**Single.blade.php**

```
 <div class="blog-main">
    {!! $post->body !!}
    <hr>
        @if($post->tags()->count() == 0)

        {{"Add Some Tags"}}

        @elseif($post->tags()->count() > 0)

         <p> <strong>Tags:</strong>
        @foreach($post->tags as $tag)

        <span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" ><a  href="{{route('tags.show',$tag->id)}}" >{{$tag->name}} </a></span>

         @endforeach </p>
         @endif
 </div>
```

Relationship with Tags and Posts

**Post Model**

```
 public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
}
```

**Tag Model**

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
```

Where do I mistake ?

Comment: what do you mean by **tags only appear in the last post** ? you have just one post !!

Comment: Nope, I have 7 seven post in my database

Comment: But here you just show one `$post = Post::find($id);` not all i think you should add index method not show !!

Comment: in this blade, I showing my blog post with their slug. I cant use index method in here

Comment: You don't need to put in the parentheses after tags when doing this check : `$post->tags()->count()`. It should be `$post->tags->count()`

Comment: where is your posts loop?

Comment: I showing just one blog post in this blade, why do I use posts loop ?

Comment: from **tags only appear in the last post** i assume you have multiple posts looped,how do you know that the post is the last post ?

Comment: can you post the relationships between your two tables?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h5p7tt, It seems on the blog

Comment: nope, not getting you

Comment: Edited and added models

Comment: You did mistake in your model

Comment: @MahfuzShishir How can I fix that ?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Model

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag', 'foreign_id');
}
```

Tag Model

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_id);
}
```

You mistake in your blade.

```
<div class="blog-main">
{!! $post->body !!}
<hr>
    @if($post->tags->count() == 0)

    {{"Add Some Tags"}}

    @elseif($post->tags->count() > 0)

     <p> <strong>Tags:</strong>
    @foreach($post->tags as $tag)

    <span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" ><a  href="{{route('tags.show',$tag->id)}}" >{{$tag->name}} </a></span>

     @endforeach </p>
     @endif
 </div>
```

Comment: use @if($post->tags->count() == 0) instead of @if($post->tags()->count() == 0)

Comment: Remove parenthesis after tags.

Comment: Removed but nothing changed.. :(

Comment: It should be work. Copy my code both blade and model and paste your project. If other process is ok then it should work.

Comment: My pleasure that it helps you... :)